# PaloAlto Application ID Signatures, 7-byte Regex Workaround

Tags: firewall, palo-alto

I'm in the process of creating some custom Application ID signatures, to give control over some in-house applications. In a nutshell, I've created signatures to match HTTP traffic using the `http-req-host-header` and `http-req-uri-path` contexts.

This works perfectly for longer paths such as:

`example.com/job-listings`

However I can't add a context match for:

`example.com/jobs`

The reason behind this, is `/jobs` is shorter than 7 characters, adding that signature fails with:

> The minimum length for this field is 7

Has anyone wrestled with this issue before? Are there any known workarounds? I can't seem to find much online. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

I have a ticket open with Palo Alto, and will update this thread with anything we manage to figure out!

Comment: Since you mentioned regex, have you tried something like `/job[s]`?

Comment: I had the same idea, it looks like the 7-bytes need to be a static string, it can't contain any wildcard characters at all.